# Rails application variables in carrierwave store_dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, store, carrierwave, dir

I am looking to use a application variable as set in application_controller

application_controller.rb

```
def current_company
 @current_company ||= Company.find(cookies[:default_company]) if cookies[:default_company]
end
```

how do I now use current_company.id in the uploader (company_logo_uploader.rb)

```
def store_dir
 "uploads/#{current_company.id}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

I get a undefined local variable or method `current_company' for :CompanyLogoUploader

help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call the instance method defined on your class with `model.` definition prepended to it

Try this

`"uploads/#{model.current_company.id}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"`

### NOTE

Make sure `@current_company` is set else it would return `nil`

Comment: In his example `current_company` was defined inside application_controller.